# Bookdown does not print table

Tags: r, bookdown

No reproducible example here as bookdown has too many dependencies, so I hope the description is enough. With current versions of bookdown, the new furniture package, etc and related packages, the following fails to generate a table in the HTML bookdown output, but the code works fine in Rmarkdown.

Here is the Rmd call:

````
```{r table 1, results='asis'}
```
````

and the associated Rchunk is:

```
 # --- table 1 ----

table1(research,
       seqquarter,
       MAIN_ORDER_MNEMONIC,
       splitby = ~new_Priority, output='markdown'
)
```

The wrapping text is all there, just no table. 
I would welcome suggestions. Thanks,

Comment: If you add four white spaces at the start of a line, StackOverflow will show it as code.  That way, you can include the tick marks and it will be more legible.

Answer (score 0):

The fault (of course) was mine .

The Rchunk had three dashes on the left side, not four.
Four is the magic number for Rchunks.

The table was printed (quite nicely, actually) in a different section of the report.